# Angular 4 services: how can I implement an async init process?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I'm building an Angular 4 service which provides access to certain data. When this service is first
instantiated, it needs to establish a connection to the data store, which is an asynchronous process.

**How can I best prevent consumers of this service (*i.e.*, components or other services) from attempting to use the service before this async connection process has completed?**

Is there some way my service can tell Angular's bootstrapper to wait for this promise to resolve before proceeding?

If it matters, the service is registered in the `providers` array of my `@NgModule`. So (as I understand it), Angular will construct a single instance of the service, which will be provided to any components or other services which inject `MyService`.

To be explicit, here's the scenario I'm afraid of:

1. During the application bootstrap process, Angular sees `MyService` in the module's `providers` array, and invokes its constructor.
2. `MyService`'s constructor begins the connection process, which could take a second or two.
3. Meanwhile, Angular's bootstrapper keeps charging ahead, and renders my application's dashboard.
4. The dashboard component injects `MyService`, and (in its own constructor, or perhaps in `ngOnInit`) attempts to call `myService.getData()` before the connection has been established.

To illustrate, here's what this service looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    private connection;

    constructor() {

        this.connect().then((connection) => {
            this.connection = connection;
            // Components should be able to consume this service once execution reaches this point, but not before!
        });

    }

    private connect(): Promise<any> {
        // (return some promise which will eventually resolve with a connection)
    }

    public getData(key: string): string {
        // (this method won't be usable until the .then() in the constructor has run)
    }


}
```

Comment: Why not return a promise or an Observable from getData() instead? That's probably what you will have to do anyway, since I guess getting data from the datastore using the connection is alwo going to be asynchronous.

Comment: That's a good thought, and that may be the thing to do. Actually, though, data access is *not* asynchronous (surprisingly enough). So if there's a way to do what I've described above, I'd prefer that (to keep data access logic simpler). Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I'm not aware of something like that at the framework level. But you can use the router and add a resolve to a parent route to prevent the router from navigating to any sub-route until the promise is fulfilled.

Comment: Could you do this manually?  Once you establish that your async connection is active, have it emit an event to your components, and have that event be your actual initialization?

Comment: @greenie2600, did you check the solution i added?

Answer (score 8):

what you need to do is delay app initialization until your connection gets established. you may do it by using `APP_INITIALIZER` token like below,

complete [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/m33PWJHzgq61MKTPQikX?p=preview)

**onAppInit Factory returning a initialize promise**

```
export function onAppInit(svc: MyService): () => Promise<any> {
  return svc.initialize;
}
```

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    MyService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: onAppInit,
      deps: [MyService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**MyService**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService{
  connection;
  
  constructor(){}
  
  initialize = (): Promise<any> => {
     return new Promise( (resolve, reject) =>  { 
         setTimeout(() => { 
          this.connection = {
             data : {
               "var1": "xyz" 
             }
          };
          resolve();
         }, 3000);
     });
  }
  
  getData = () => {
    console.log(this.connection);
    return this.connection.data;
  }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello</h1>
  <hr />
  {{data | json}}
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  data;
  constructor(private svc: MyService){ }
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.data = this.svc.getData();
  }
}
```

***This works as you asked in your problem, but note that your application will not render until the service is initialized, and that may be bad user experience depending on how much delay is acceptable***

The better solution would be return a promise or an Observable from getData() as @JBNizet suggested in comment.